# Top of Header Slider image show <li> numbers in the webpage (Magento 1.7)

Tags: html, html-lists, magento-1.7

I added a Header Slider image to the admin portal of Magento 1.7, but the number of `<li>` appears on my page. How can I hide the number of `<li>`? The following is my code in the admin portal of Magento 1.7:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-" style="width: 100%;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img {{retinaurl data-img-src="wysiwyg/banner/ISQ_bigSlider1.png" data-img-srcX2="wysiwyg/banner/ISQ_bigSlider1.png" alt=""}}style="width: 100%; margin-right: 20px;">
      </div>

<div class="item active">
        <<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/banner/ISQ_Safety_Glove_Poster_AprUpdated.jpg"}}" alt="" />}}style="width: 100%; margin-right: 20px;">
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my output picture in my webpage, but will appear 1,2,3,4
[image: output]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem, or help to point out which part of my coding is getting errors. Thanks.